# Why my phonegap android showing a black blank page?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've following this [Phonegap guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android). when I run my own android application, it shows nothing, just blank page. why it shows blank page?
I'm using cordova-1.8.1

here is my android activity:

```
package report.weeklyflash;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MenuPhonegap extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 

    <head> 
        <title>PhoneGap</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script> 
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1> 
    </body> 

</html>
```

here is my directory structure and screenshot when I run this project:
[image]
[image]

UPDATE: when I try to delete `index.html` file, it still not showing any error message, just blank page. and log stops on `DroidGap.onCreate()`

Comment: Where in the directory structure of your project does index.html exist? I think something's amiss here. If your app is missing index.html or if it's in the wrong place it'll display an error saying so.

Comment: Is not giving any errors? Because I don't see anything wrong with your code. Probably is your build path, try cleaning your project and see if that helps.

Comment: @jlafay I've update my thread to show my directory structure. and It's not showing any error message.

Comment: @0gravity yes, It's not showing any error message. ok, I will try to clean it first because I create this new activity on existing project.

Comment: UPDATE: when I try to delete `index.html` file, it still not showing any error message, just blank page. and log stops on `DroidGap.onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, I've put a wrong name of activity on my android manifest.

so I solve this problem by changing the activity name on android manifest into the correct name. here is my android manifest after I solve it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="report.weeklyflash"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name="MenuActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".WeeklyFlashIdActivity"></activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="MenuPhonegap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So is that what the yellow warning icon over your manifest file's icon in your project was? I've never had the wrong activity name so I'm not sure if eclipse is smart enough to find that and complain when it's wrong.

Comment: @jlafay well, it just useless warning..I have 3 activities and I just want to use 1 activity, and I gave the wrong activity name, so the eclipse can't find something wrong because it's a valid activity name. Basically, it's my fault :p